# A neural network outputting vectors with all components NaN

Tags: tensorflow

My neural network code ends up outputting vectors with NaNs most of the time. The code is given below:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

from six.moves import xrange

import time

import os

from glob import glob

from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED

import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf

## Defining variables which have to be provided by user

## Defining the number of units in the RNN. This is also the size of the word
## and document embeddings
num_units = 100

##The number of data elements in a batch
batch_size = 1

##The folder where the npz files with the numpy arrays are stored.
npz_files_folder = "npz_files"

## Name of the file to which we want the model to be saved
model_file = "rnn_trial"

## Number of labels sampled from the noise for NCE
num_sampled = 50

## The dropout probability for the NN
dropout = 0.2

## The learning rate for the optimizer
lr = 0.1

## The number of epochs
epochs = 10

## Reading in the list of npz files with vectors for each document
doc_files = sorted(glob(os.path.join(npz_files_folder, "*.npz")))

num_classes = num_docs = len(doc_files)


## The tensor for storing a batch of sentences where each sentence is a
## sequence of word embeddings. This is an input to the NN
sentences = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, None, num_units],
    name='sentences')


## The tensor for storing a batch of documents where each document is a
## sequence of sentence embeddings. This is an input to the NN
documents = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, None, num_units])

## The tensor for storing the labels for each batch of documents
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size])

## Here we define the LSTM used in the first layer
sent_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units)
sent_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(sent_lstm,
    output_keep_prob=1.0-dropout)

## We define the initial_state of the LSTM in first layer here
initial_state_sent_lstm = sent_lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

## Here we get the outputs and states from the first layer
outputs_lstm, states_lstm = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(sent_lstm,
    inputs=sentences, initial_state=initial_state_sent_lstm)

## Here we define the forward GRU used in the second layer
doc_gru_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_units//2)
initial_state_doc_gru_fw = doc_gru_fw.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

## Here we define the reverse GRU used in second layer.
doc_gru_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_units-num_units//2)
initial_state_doc_gru_bw = doc_gru_bw.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

## Here we get the outputs and states from the second layer
outputs_gru, states_gru = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=doc_gru_fw,
    cell_bw=doc_gru_bw, initial_state_fw=initial_state_doc_gru_fw,
    initial_state_bw=initial_state_doc_gru_bw,
    inputs=documents)
# outputs_gru, states_gru = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=doc_gru_fw,
#     cell_bw=doc_gru_bw,
#     inputs=documents, dtype=tf.float32)


## The final document embeddings
final_output = tf.reduce_mean(tf.concat(outputs_gru, 2), axis=1)

sigmoid_W = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([num_units, 1],
    stddev=1.0/np.sqrt(num_units)))
sigmoid_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1], dtype=tf.float32))

logits = tf.matmul(final_output, sigmoid_W) + sigmoid_b

y_ = (num_docs - 1) * tf.sigmoid(tf.reshape(logits, [-1]))

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_ - labels))

## Defining the training step
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)

## Initializing the session
sess = tf.Session()

## Initializing the variables
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

t = time.time()

for n in xrange(epochs):
    result = False

    for j, doc in enumerate(doc_files):

        # if j==100:
        #     break

        try:
            npz_file = np.load(doc, allow_pickle=False)
        except ValueError:
            continue

        train_label = np.array([j])

        sent_files = sorted(npz_file.files)

        temp_doc = np.array([])
        temp_doc = np.reshape(temp_doc, (0, num_units))

        for i, sent_file in enumerate(sent_files):
            sent_input = np.reshape(npz_file[sent_file], (1, -1, num_units))

            if 0 in sent_input.shape:
                continue

            output_1 = sess.run(outputs_lstm, 
                                feed_dict={sentences: sent_input})

            sent_embed = output_1[:, -1:]

            temp_doc = np.concatenate([temp_doc] + list(sent_embed), 0)

        ## Training the model
        temp_doc = np.array([temp_doc])
        _, doc_vector = sess.run([train, final_output], feed_dict={
            documents: temp_doc, labels: train_label})

        if np.isnan(np.sum(doc_vector)):
            result = True

    print(result)
    print("Finished with epoch ", n)
    print()


doc_vecs_file_name = model_file + "_doc_vecs.zip"

with ZipFile(doc_vecs_file_name, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, True) as myzip:

    for doc in doc_files:
        # if doc_files.index(doc)==100:
        #     break

        try:
            npz_file = np.load(doc, allow_pickle=False)
        except ValueError:
            continue

        sent_files = sorted(npz_file.files)

        temp_doc = np.array([])
        temp_doc = np.reshape(temp_doc, (0, num_units))

        for i, sent_file in enumerate(sent_files):
            sent_input = np.reshape(npz_file[sent_file], (1, -1, num_units))

            if 0 in sent_input.shape:
                continue

            output_1 = sess.run(outputs_lstm, 
                                feed_dict={sentences: sent_input})

            sent_embed = output_1[:, -1:]

            temp_doc = np.concatenate([temp_doc] + list(sent_embed), 0)

        ## Training the model
        temp_doc = np.array([temp_doc])
        doc_vec = sess.run(final_output, feed_dict={documents: temp_doc})

        temp_file = doc.split(os.sep)[-1][:-4] + ".csv"
        np.savetxt(temp_file, doc_vec, delimiter=',')
        myzip.write(temp_file)
        os.remove(temp_file)



saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, model_file)

print("Time taken = ", (time.time() - t))
```

If needed, I can upload a sample data set which you can use to try running the code yourself. With that sample data set, occasionally the training is completed without any NaNs creeping in. But, most of the time, NaNs pop up while training.

I am using tensorflow version 1.1.0 alongwith python 2.7.13 from the anaconda distribution.

Comment: did you try reducing learning rate to 0.01 or 0.001 ??

Comment: Hello, when I reduced the learning rate to 0.001, I got clean vectors most of the time. But, occasionally, NaNs still creep in on some runs of the code. I am trying to reduce the learning rate further to see if that helps. Why do large values of learning rates produce NaNs?? Can you please shed some light on this??

Comment: I tried reducing the learning rate till 1e-6, but still on some trial runs, NaNs pop up. The thing is, it takes a long time to run the entire data set through the training and I don't want to run the entire set again and find NaNs.

Comment: Hello, I also tried installing tensorflow 1.2.1 to see if the NaNs were due to a bug in 1.1.0 that might have been fixed in a newer version. But, I am still getting NaNs. BTW, did you get a chance to look at the code?? Does it look okay??

Comment: Can someone please help me with this?? If necessary, I can upload a sample data set which you can use to reproduce the issue I am having.